# How to create hints for personal functions in VS Code

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I want to make a personal library with all my js functions written. 
 
What I really need is that I need the intellisense of VS Code to show me more hints about this functions - type of the input variables, type of the return, maybe some information about the function. 
For example - a hint for substring looks like this: 
[image]
and a hint for my function looks like this:
[image]
 
Digging a bit in VS Code I was able to find, that there are .ts files with declaration of objects, interfaces and functions (for example declaration of substring() in lid.es6.d.ts, etc.)
[image] 
My first thought is whether I can make a personal .ts file with declaration of all my functions and make the intellisense refer to it too.

Comment: Just a suggestion, give typescript a try, you will get the nice hints you are looking for because Typescript allows you to specify the argument types, also the output of typescript is plain TS, so you will be able to use your library anywhere you could have used it before

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You don't need a .d.ts for your javascript functions, you can just use a jsDoc comment. Ex:

```
/**
 * Does stuff
 * @param {Number} params 
 */
function myFun(params) {


}
```

Between `{}` is the type of the parameter. You can also add a description to your function.

VsCode will pick-up JsDoc comments and use them to show you hints. Also if you type `/**` and then press tab above a function it will insert a property formatted jsDoc comment base on your function to give you a starting point.

JsDoc reference [here](http://usejsdoc.org/)

**Note:** Give typescript a try, you will get the nice hints you are looking for because Typescript allows you to specify the argument types, also the output of typescript is plain TS, so you will be able to use your library anywhere you could have used it before

Comment: Thanks, apparently I will need both - the JSDoc and the TypeScript. Any idea where / how to put reference to the .ts file, so that VS Code will start picking up declarations from there too?

Comment: You plan to write the code in Typescript ? Or you want to write Javascript and use `.ts` files to augment your hints ?

Comment: I plan to write JS code and use the .ts to display hints. Here is the thing - where I work we write JS scripts, but we execute them in another software, where there are few API's. I have documentation for the API functions, but I don't have their code. And every time I use a call to this functions I have to make sure I check how many parameters where are, etc. This is what I need the ts file for. Hope this makes sense. And on the other hand I still have my small functions where I will use JSDoc.

Comment: You can place the `.d.ts` anywhere in your structure and add a reference comment in your js Ex: `/// <reference path="definitions.d.ts" />`. This will tell vscode to look pick up any definitions from there.

Comment: Just as a personal opinion, if you will be writing a .d.ts for this external application anyway, you might as well try using TS for you code. The compilation result will pe JS you can execute anywhere just as you had written it yourself. And your coding expierence and quality will have to gain

Comment: Strano, weird, I have added this example but yet I still have nothing but just one row e.g. `function mysqlDatetoJs(mysqlTimeStamp: any): Date` not the hint. I suspect the intelephense or something else could interfere with the VScode built in engine. I have the same problem/output as in the initial question

Answer (score 5):

Yes you could write your own typings. If you don't want to use TS, you can use the JSDoc standard:

```
/**
 * Get a survey's details and possible answers by id
 * @param {Number} surveyId
 */ 
const getById = async (surveyId) => {
    ...
}
```

VSC is smart enough to read all that and display it when implementing.
Especially when you build services which are exported and the imported this works great.

JSDoc info: http://usejsdoc.org/about-getting-started.html